# A-Frame VR: Image not showing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, webvr

**EDIT:** The problem was that I ran the HTML file from my own harddrive and not a web server. Everything opened just fine when I put it on my web server and ran it from there.

**A-Frame Ver:** 0.4.0, **Chrome:** 55.0.2883.87, **Firefox:** 50.1.0, **OS:** Win 10 (64bit).

I am new to A-Frame and am currently playing around with different elements and entities. When I tried to add an image entity but was only met with a
[blank plane [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vlfq.png). However, the exact same HTML file opened in Firefox [showed the image [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YenA.jpg). I've disabled all potential blockers in Chrome (uBlock Origin, etc.) but the image still doesn't show.

Here is the HTML file I ran in both browsers:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Testing A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: true">

    <a-assets>
      <img id="my-image" src="apple_fruit.png">
    </a-assets>

    <a-image position="0 1.5 -2" src="#my-image"></a-image>


      <a-plane rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
      
      <a-entity position="0 0 -1">
        <a-camera>
          <a-cursor></a-cursor>
        </a-camera>
      </a-entity>

    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in your JS console?

Comment: Yes! It showed that A-Frame couldn't find the directory because I ran it from my computer and not a web server. Everything opened just fine when I put it on a server and ran from it!

Comment: You should put that edit with what fixed your problem as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed!**
The problem was that I ran the HTML file from my own harddrive and not a web server. Everything opened just fine when I put it on my web server and ran it from there.

Comment: Indeed, see also the section of the FAQ dedicated to CORS https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/introduction/faq.html#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-load